# RequireJS returning a function from module to be used in template

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am wanting to create a function in a module which would work with various dependencies but called in the template, so far I have only received a function undefined error. Where am I going wrong, or is this simply not possible?

helper.js module

```
define(['aDependency'],function(){

    var sayHi = function(){
        console.log('Hi');
};
return{
    sayHi: sayHi
}
```

This module is required in my main file

```
requirejs(['lib/helper']);
```

And I would like to use the function in my template;

```
<button data-remodal-action="confirm" onClick="sayHi()"/>
```

However I am getting an undefinde function.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to call `sayHi` function like it's in the global scope, but it's not because requirejs modules has isolated scope

To use it like this - `<button data-remodal-action="confirm" onClick="sayHi()"/>`
you should do something like

```
requirejs(['lib/helper'], function(helper){
    window.sayHi = helper.sayHi;
});
```

But it's an antipattern to set global variables that will be call from HTML. I'd propose you to do something like this

HTML:

```
<button id="sayHiButton" data-remodal-action="confirm"></button>
```

JS:

```
requirejs(['lib/helper'], function(helper){
    document.getElementById('sayHiButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
         helper.sayHi();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that

```
<button data-remodal-action="confirm" onClick="sayHi()"/>
```

points to a global function.

Your `sayHi()` function is part of object which your `helper` module returns. That is not global at all. If you want to add that function as click event on a button, you must do that where it is visible.

That is inside helper module

```
define(['aDependency'],function(){

    var sayHi = function(){
        console.log('Hi');
    };
    $('button').click(sayHi);
return{
    sayHi: sayHi
}
```

or

inside module that uses helper module:

```
requirejs(['lib/helper'], function (helper) {
  $('button').click(helper.sayHi);
});
```